# jqGrid record count has space before the thousands digit

Tags: jquery-plugins, jqgrid

When the record count in jqGrid exceeds 1000, there is a visible space between the hundreds and thousands digits. See image below (taken from the jqGrid demo page)

[alt text http://img180.imageshack.us/img180/3066/jqgridspace.png](http://img180.imageshack.us/img180/3066/jqgridspace.png)

Is there a way to remove this space, or replace it with with a standard thousands separator (comma or other)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the pre-defined formatter options.  Here is a [link](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter):

**EDIT:**

Thought I'd give credit to [Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315935/oleg) and paste his comment below wherein he actually does the work to give the code from the documentation:

> If you redefine $.jgrid.formatter.integer as following $.jgrid.formatter.integer = {thousandsSeparator: ""}; you will see all integers in jqGrid inclusive the total records number formated without blanks as the separator of thousands. – [Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315935/oleg) May 20 '10 at 8:52

Thanks, Oleg!

Comment: Looks like this formatter works only for cell content and not for the built in row/pages control.

Comment: @Ron Harlev: Bradley Mountford wrote do correct information. If you redefine `$.jgrid.formatter.integer` as following `$.jgrid.formatter.integer = {thousandsSeparator: ""};` you will see all integers in jqGrid inclusive the total records number formated without blanks as the separator of thousands.

Answer (score 4):

changed file grid.locale-en.js 
from 
`integer : {thousandsSeparator: " ", defaultValue: '0'}` 
to
`integer : {thousandsSeparator: ",", defaultValue: '0'}`
to add comma "," as thousands separator